# Who was the nitrogenised girl?

Tags: character, titans, doom-patrol

In *Titans* S01E04, we see Chief treating a girl who got nitrogenised. But we never see her again in *Titans* or *Doom Patrol* and we don't get to know what happen to her after treatment. Is it any nod to the comics? Is she any prominent DC character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patient's name is [Shyleen Lao](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7342436/?ref_=ttep_ep4). She is DC superheroine [Fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fever_(DC_Comics)). According to wikipedia, she appeared in

- [Doom Patrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_Patrol) (in 2001, volume 3 #1 (her first appearance))
- [Teen Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans) (#59)
- [Terror Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terror_Titans) (#1, she was slain)

> She has power over heat transfer and, to a degree, fire.

In [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/titans-shyleen-lao-fever-dc-universe/), Matt Morrison wrote in November 2018:

> It remains to be seen if Fever will be making a guest appearance in the new ***Doom Patrol*** series, after her cameo on ***Titans***. It seems unlikely, however, given that she was never tremendously popular and was unceremoniously killed off with little fanfare in 2008. Fever also has not been listed among other characters from the *Doom Patrol* comics expected to appear in the new show, like Crazy Jane or Mister Nobody.

Comment: Shayleen Lao is played by Hina Abdullah. Kevin Melrose wrote in [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/titans-tv-doom-patrol-celsius-fever/) that before the epsiode aired, the mysterious guest was expected to be *Celsius* (aka Arani Desai) and "Heck, photos released before the episode's premiere even identified actress Hina Abdullah as Arani Desai. But in the episode itself, The Chief refers to the woman as Shyleen Lao."

Comment: Celsius appeared in a recent episode (season 1 episode 5?)